# How to disable a EditText

Tags: android, datepicker, kotlin, android-edittext

How can I do disable a EditText after writing something,so that it stays with that value and can not be modified.Because I did a EditText with a button , and the EditText when I click in the button get the value of the date using a date picker, but I want that in this EditText can not be write

Comment: [Try googling before asking on Stack overflow. There are answers out there](https://www.google.ca/search?ei=ofY0W9qFBcXO9APmt5_4Bg&q=disable+edit+text&oq=disable+edit+text&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i10k1l2j0l4j0i22i30k1l2j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1.3893.7774.0.7879.27.23.4.0.0.0.120.1675.17j5.23.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.27.1740.6..35i39k1j0i67k1j0i131k1j0i20i263k1.68.5XYz7xcH2nA)

Answer (score 4):

You can disable edittext programmatically (In java/kt file).
you can use below code in kotlin.

```
edittext.text = "your text" //sets text in edittext
edittext.enabled = false  //disables edittext field
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the EditText always disabled.

```
edittext.isEnabled = false
```

And when the button is clicked set the value of EditText to the desired date string.

```
edittext.text = "DD/MM/YYYY"
```

This way the EditText will not be writable but you can set the value using the button.

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute android:inputType="date"and android:onClick="your_function" to bind the click on your edittext to a function

Here's an example of activity MainActivity.kt :

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
        lateinit var editTextDate: EditText;

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            editTextDate = findViewById(R.id.edittext_date);
        }

        fun openPickerDate(view : View) {
            val c = Calendar.getInstance()
            val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

            val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                editTextDate.setText("" + dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year)
            }, year, month, day)
            dpd.show()
        }
    }
```

Here's layout activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="01/01/2018"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:onClick="openPickerDate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```